# Android WebView not redirecting to another page. SPA website

Tags: java, android, webview

I got a website and I want the website to become a mobile app since it is responsive. I decided to make it as a WebView since it is the easier to do because I am not a mobile dev. My website uses Laravel + Vuejs SPA (single page application). But after I log in when I click to the navbar, It does not redirect me to the next page. Can someone tell me what I missed? Does it concern my website or its just an android problem?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.carrental;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView web;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        web = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
        web.loadUrl("http://52.74.70.6:90/");

    }

    private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideKeyEvent(WebView view, KeyEvent event) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.carrental">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can watch your url redirection when website open in web view by below code

```
 public class PaymentWebActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    private String link = "";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_paymentview);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            link = getIntent().getExtras().getString("link");
        }
        initWebView();
    }

    private void initWebView() {
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        WebViewClientImpl webViewClient = new WebViewClientImpl(this);
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
        webView.loadUrl(link);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && this.webView.canGoBack()) {
            this.webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    public class WebViewClientImpl extends WebViewClient {

        public WebViewClientImpl(Activity activity) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
            if (url.indexOf(link) > -1) return false;
            Log.e("Url :", url);
            checkUrl(webView, url);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, WebResourceRequest webResourceRequest) {
            if (webResourceRequest.getUrl().toString().indexOf(link) > -1) return false;
            Log.e("Url :", webResourceRequest.getUrl().toString());
            checkUrl(webView, webResourceRequest.getUrl().toString());
            return false;
        }

    }

    private void checkUrl(WebView webView, String url) {
        if (checkSuccessUrl(url)) {
            webView.destroy();
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
            finish();
        } else if (checkErrorUrl(url)) {
            webView.destroy();
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            String errorMessage = uri.getQueryParameter("message");
            showConfirmDialog(errorMessage);
        }
    }

    private void showConfirmDialog(String errorMessage) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(PaymentWebActivity.this);
        Window w = dialog.getWindow();
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_error);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        lp.copyFrom(w.getAttributes());
        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        w.setAttributes(lp);
        w.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

        TextView lbltitle = (TextView) w.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        lbltitle.setText(CommonFunctions.getInstance().getArabicText(PaymentWebActivity.this, "APP Name"));
        lbltitle.setTypeface(CommonFunctions.getInstance().getRegular(PaymentWebActivity.this));

        TextView lblmessage = (TextView) w.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
        lblmessage.setText(CommonFunctions.getInstance().getArabicText(PaymentWebActivity.this, errorMessage));
        lblmessage.setTypeface(CommonFunctions.getInstance().getRegular(PaymentWebActivity.this));

        Button btnOk = (Button) w.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
        btnOk.setText(CommonFunctions.getInstance().getArabicText(PaymentWebActivity.this, "OK"));
        btnOk.setTypeface(CommonFunctions.getInstance().getBold(PaymentWebActivity.this));
        btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                finish();
            }
        });

        Button btnCancel = (Button) w.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        btnCancel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        /*btnCancel.setText(CommonFunctions.getInstance().getArabicText(PaymentWebActivity.this, "Cancel"));
        btnCancel.setTypeface(CommonFunctions.getInstance().getBold(PaymentWebActivity.this));
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });*/

        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    private boolean checkSuccessUrl(String url) {
        return url.contains("success.php");
    }

    private boolean checkErrorUrl(String url) {
        return url.contains("error.php");
    }
}
```

- success.php
- error.php

these two files are created on a server side so when checkUrl found this files we can execute our logic as per the url. you can also forward page as per the found.

Comment: see in my post I have give you whole page code but from server side you need to create the files which you want to forward user. I my code I have mention two files (success.php and error.php) so these file are watch by the override url loading method so once it find the particular file you can identify that which file you need to forward

Comment: but i am using a framework. is it okay if i only put a route there like `localhost/success`?

Comment: in my web its laravel + vue

Comment: actually.i have no idea about the framework but you can achieve your goal like this it needs the url to execute so you can set the final url which you want to execute if its work on localhost or with domain

Comment: so its okay if i only return a route? but the code says `contains` meaning it will search for the file?

Comment: you can set route by server but you can identify from the url loading method so you can redirect user as per your requirement

Comment: im confused sorry. can you help me more about this?

Comment: I am not sure you can get the URL if you're using a framework that utilize SPA. Webview is not a good option for SPA web.